# Where do I find the sdk tools tab

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I want to start using Layout Constraints with Android, but one of the first steps is to go to the SDK Tools tab in the SDK Manager to download the necessary tools. However, when I open my SDK manager, I don't see any SDK Tools tab.

[image: Mac SDK Manager]

I've tried downloading the newest version of the tools package from the Android Developer Website, and replace the tools directory in my sdk directory, but that didn't change anything. Is this just how it is with the Mac version of SDK Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you find the SDK Tools tab:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are presently viewing the **Standalone SDK manager**, with respect to the image you posted.

To view the SDK Tools tab, Use the following steps:

Click on **Android Studio** at the top left of your screen.
Then click on **Preferences** > **Appearance & Behaviour** > **System Settings** > **Android SDK**.

You should see the **SDK Tools Tab** on this page.

Comment: I do not appear to have an Android SDK submenu: https://s29.postimg.org/o71gzfbo7/Screen_Shot_2017_01_02_at_12_46_36.png

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Android Studio 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

For ConstraintLayout you will require Android Studio 2.2.
Go to bottom, in Extras check Android Support Repositories and  install them
Then go to layout file i.e any activity xml file and rightclick on the parent layout like RelativeLayout and select Convert RelativeLayout to ConstraintLayout, it will ask you weather to add 
    `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'` or something like this in gradle file, so allow it and then it will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install all the necessary tools and components from the stand alone sdk manager as shown in your image.

If you don't have the Android SDK submenu no worries.

I am using Android Studio 2.2 on mac & it does have the submenu.

What version are you using?

Comment: Android Studio 2.2.3

Comment: Then it should be there. Update your sdk tools from stand alone sdk manager then see if it's visible.